# C: передача строк между функциями

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Изуаю работу со строками в языке С.
Я столкнулся с ситуацией:

я присваиваю значение строке :

```
char name2[256] = "default";
```

Передаю ее в функцию:

```
GetName(name2);
```

Сама функция:

```
void GetName(char* name)
{
    printf("%s \n", name); //сюда передаетммя парвильное значение
    name = "22";
    printf("%s \n", name); //сюда устанавливается правильное значение
}
```

Т.к. я передавал указатель на строку, я расчитывадл на то, что в массиве `char name2[256]` после выполнения фукнции будет НОВОЕ значение, т.е. "22", а не "default".

Подскажте, пожалуйста, что я делаю не правильно?

Спасибо!

Comment: Во втором случае вы перетираете переменную `name="22";` это ещё можно, но следующей строкой вы перетираете константу 22, это чревато разрушением data-сегмента и доолгой ловлей жуков (багов). Если вам так уж нужно скопировать 22, воспользуйтесь `strcpy(name,"22")` А если вам так уж хочется влиять на переданную переменную в функцию, то пишите `GetName(char*& name)` но константу тереть - нельзя.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо за совет! Вы предлагаете отказаться от оператора "=" при работе со строками и использовать вместо него strcpy?

Comment: это два разных действия, которые приведут к разному поведению программы. В первом случае, вы перетираете указатель на строку, которую вам передали, на константу. А во втором случае вы копируете значение константы 22 в значение, на которое указывает переданный вам указатель. Нужно немного времени что бы понять чем значение отличается от указателя.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо за совет, я понял куда дальше копать. а функция strcpy решает текущую проблему. Спасибо!

Comment: @nick_n_a: "...но следующей строкой вы перетираете константу 22, это чревато разрушением data-сегмента" - это о чем вообще??? Где вы тут увидели "константу 22" и какое-то ее "перетирание"? Что это за феерическая бессмыслица? Откуда? О каком `char*& name` может идти речь в языке С?

Comment: @nick_n_a К чему все это здесь? Я еще раз повторяю вопрос, жирным шрифтом: **где вы в этом коде увидели перезапись константы** и каких-то "соседей"? Где??? Покажите пальцем.

Comment: Я перепутал printf с sprintf

Comment: Хотя... тут есть ещё константа "default" не могу точно сказать компилятор перетрет "default", или скопирует "default" в выделеный буфер отдав на растерзание GetName. Не помню как с себя ведёт в таком случае.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Компилятор, разумеется, использует `"default"` для инициализации независимого, локального и свободно  модифицируемого буфера `name2`. Никаких других вариантов тут нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, изначально никакое значение своей строке вы не "присваиваете". Голые массивы в С не поддерживают *присваивание* вообще. А это

```
char name2[256] = "default";
```

называется *инициализация*, а не "присваивание". Инициализация символьных массивов поддерживает такой синтаксис в виде исключения.

А, во-вторых, вот это

```
name = "22";
```

уже действительно *присваивание*. Однако `name` внутри функции в этом случае уже никакой не массив, а локальный указатель на начало вашего массива `name2`. Менять этот локальный указатель вы можете как угодно, но этим вы не оказываете никакого воздействия на массив `name2`.

Хотите поместить новое значение в ваш массив `name2`? Либо делайте это вручную явно поэлементно, либо пользуетесь готовыми библиотечными функциями вроде `memcpy` или `strcpy`. Других способов копирования отдельностоящих массивов в С нет. Это относится и к строкам, и к любым массивам вообще.

Answer (score 1):

У вас две ошибки.

Одна ошибка в том, что `name2` не может изменять свое значение, так что ваша попытка

```
name = "22";
```

неверна. Вернее, она *была бы просто недопустима*, если бы не ваша вторая ошибка - в C аргументы передаются в функцию по значению, и ваш аргумент `name` - это просто локальная переменная функции, содержащая значение указателя, переданное ей при вызове. Так что как бы вы ни меняли само значение `name` в функции - это никак не отразится на исходном массиве.

Но - вы можете менять через этот указатель то, на что он указывает - так что

```
srtcpy(name,"22");
```

дало бы тот результат, который вам нужен.